# Django importing FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:

Tags: python, django

I tried to import the folder `covid_data` with files, so that I can use functions from the file `coviddata`(which reads csv files from its directory), but I've been stuck for a while here. It yields lines of errors with `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: restrictions.csv.`

I tried joining directories, but to no avail. Tried creating a separate `static` folder with csv files and moving `coviddata.py` to plots (the same directory as **views.py**) with then `restrictions=pd.read_csv(static/restrictions.csv)`, which also didn't work.
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zZwIj.jpg)

Comment: have you tried to potentially upload the file to a CDN and reference it through an external link?

Comment: hi! do you mean converting the plot and embedding it into HTML? I used bokeh for the interactive plot and CDN will probably lose it, but thanks!

Comment: Can you show the code for coviddata.py. I suspect that your opening the file as if your in the same dir ie with something like `with open("restrictions.csv") as res_file` but this will say look in the current dir your in, not look in the dir that the coviddata.py is in. you should try giving it the full path to the file or at least a relative path as django will not be running in the covid_data dir where the csv file is

Comment: @Pat a CDN would hold your file online but allow you to reference it in your code. It's like when you use bootstrap or any other HTML library that you need to include a link to .css/.js files online

Comment: @Chris Doyle so I changed it to a separate static folder with csv files [link](https://ibb.co/RDyHJrn)

Comment: @vladthelad okay, i'll try that

Comment: you can even do it by adding the file to github and referencing that url

Comment: @ChrisDoyle I included absolute paths to those csv files and it worked! As simple as that. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Once you add the csv files under the static folder in your application directory structure.

```
from django.templatetags.static import static
url = static('restrictions.csv')
```

You can use this code to get the url for the static file under static/restrictions.csv. Django will be able to resolve the FileNotFound issue.

Comment: Sorry, like this? [link](https://ibb.co/jr0ZVfp), [link](https://ibb.co/Pg5QD6n) It doesn't work :/ but thanks!

Comment: Hi, the static folder should not be under any other directory it should be directly under project directory.

Comment: I solved it the next day, just had to include absolute paths instead, thanks though!